# UrlFetchApp working in Apps Script but not Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch, custom-function

I built a simple function that calls an API and returns data. I will attach the code below. When I run the test() function with "VGI" it works perfectly every time I try it. When I call `=DIVIDEND_HISTORY("VGI")` in google sheets I get a 403 authentication error blocked 90% of the time. What is causing this to run differently in sheets vs script? Is there anything I can do? When actual API is:

https://seekingalpha.com/api/v3/symbols/vgi/dividend_history?group_by=quarterly&sort=-date

Code:

```js
function test() {
  Logger.log(dividend_history("VGI"));
}

function dividend_history(sym) {

  var sym1 = String(sym).toLowerCase();

  var url = "https://seekingalpha.com/api/v3/symbols/"+sym1+"/dividend_history?group_by=quarterly&sort=-date";

  var jsonData = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()).data;

  var processed_data = jsonData.map(({...item}) => item.attributes).map(({split_adj_factor, declare_date, year, date, record_date, amount, ...item}) => item);


  return [[processed_data[0].ex_date, processed_data[0].pay_date, processed_data[0].adjusted_amount, processed_data[0].freq]];
}
```

Comment: This was in fact due to seekingalpha blocking the requests. You ARE able to use UrlFetchApp within a custom function. After changing the URL to a provider that does not limit requests I was able to source the same information for over 100 securities without issue.

Comment: Oh you're right I had that wrong about UrlFetchApp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried this and it worked on the first run but failed on every succeeding runs of the script. This means that it doesn't matter if the function was ran on script or on sheet.

The possible assumption for this is that the server(seekingalpha) blocks your IP after running the script once because it detected your session/request as a bot/script generated.

Comment: You are completely correct! I switched urls and the function is now working perfectly. Thank you